# Hiding Variables in a Prolog Query

Tags: lambda, prolog

I am working on an assignment with prolog which involves an airport database (it has airport cities, and flight links which includes airport tax and duration time) and the first question involves queries. We are supposed to write a Prolog query to answer a question, I already know how to answer the question the problem is Prolog is outputing more information then I want. The query I wrote is:

```
flight(X,_,Y,_,N), N > 180.
```

Basically all it does is list out all cities (X is origin flight, and Y is the destination flight and N is duration). I want X and Y but I do not want N. The only way I can think of getting this to work is by wrapping this query in a rule and just having it display X and Y, but since we are not supposed to write rules I am not sure how to get around this. I do not really want an explicit answer just maybe a hint or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where possible I prefer use expressions to compact IO

```
?- forall((flight(X,_,Y,_,N), N > 180),
           writeln((x=X,y=Y))).
```

for instance, with a different generator

```
?- forall((member(X,"12"),member(Y,"ab")),writeln((x=X,y=Y))).
x=49,y=97
x=49,y=98
x=50,y=97
x=50,y=98
true.
```

Of course, to properly indent tables [format](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=format/2)/2 will do much better...

**edit**
maybe I misunderstood the question, supposing you already considered

```
query(X,Y) :-
  flight(X,_,Y,_,N), N > 180.
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the answer although we are not allowed to use any helper predicates which would probably include forall... it works though so that is a good piece of knowledge even if I am not allowed to use it, I am sure something like that might help with the other parts of the assignment!

Comment: Hey thanks for the update, I actually did think of that but I am not actually clear whether or not I can do that since that would require writing out a rule. I know then in the query I would just ask query(X,Y) and it would work, but in the assignment it says "For each of questions (a)-(e) listed below, write a Prolog query (not a rule!) that will answer the question using flight/5 and airport/3 predicates, and any other logic you need.

Comment: I might just be misunderstanding the rules of the assignment (no pun intended :))

Answer (score 1):

Jekejeke Prolog provides a unique solution to this problem. It allows
the (^)/2 operator to appear in top-level queries. So if you have:

```
?- [user].
flight(a,1,b,2,100).
flight(c,3,d,4,200).
^D
```

You normally will get the following answer, and N might annoy you:

```
?- flight(X,_,Y,_,N), N > 180.
X = c,
Y = d,
N = 200
```

You can now hide N as follows:

```
?- N^(flight(X,_,Y,_,N), N>180).
X = c,
Y = d
```

The use of (^)/2 for this purpose stems from the role of
(^)/2 already found in the bagof/3 and setof/3 predicates.

Bye

Comment: Hmm... interesting, I have not written in prolog since this class but if I ever decide to get back into it I will try to remember this. I know we have an AI class where we have to write in prolog so if I take that class this would probably something good to remember :)

Comment: In many implementations, (^)/2 is implemented as `(_^G) :- G.`

Comment: The (^)/2 corresponds to sigma/1 and (\\)/2 in lambda Prolog: [lists] ?- sigma Y\ append X Y (1::nil). X = nil http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~dale/lProlog/proghol/extract.html

Answer (score 1):

Using [`library(lambda)`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl) you can declare those variables that should remain visible.

```
?- {X,Y}+\ ( flight(X,_,Y,_,N), N > 180 ).
   X = c, Y = d.
```

Answer (score 0):

For a one-off query like this, I often use a simple print statement like:

```
flight(X,_,Y,_,N), N > 180, print(('X' = X, 'Y' = Y)), nl, fail.
```

The downsides of this are:

1. The output can be ugly unless you put work into formatting it.  Here I'm constructing a `,/2` term (with `=/2` subterms) which should be rendered similarly to Prolog output for ordinary goal solutions.
2. Worse, the goal actually fails (to prevent it succeeding it printing all the many spurious bindings such as those for `N`) so can be difficult to use in something larger.

But it's the quickest way I know of to print a set of solutions to a goal entered on the command line, while hiding all the working variables.

Answer (score -1):

Does the following provides an acceptable solution? `findall` finds all the unifications of a given term satisfying given a given goal. Therefore you can format your answers as you wish.

```
findall([X, Y], (flight(X, _, Y, _, N), N > 180), Solutions).
```